# C++ Calculator With Unlimited Inputs

Tags: c++

Hi I am a beginner to the c++ language and I would like to know if there is any way of writing a program with unlimited inputs. For example: I want to write a calculator program just to add numbers. That's easy enough but is there a way so that the user can add as many numbers as he wants without being asked how many numbers he wants. Such that if he wants to add three numbers he can just type "1+1+1" or if he wants to add four numbers he adds "+1" to the end of the previous line.Like this the user is not stuck to a fixed number of inputs or so he doesn't need to be asked how many inputs he wants. What functions in c++ do I need to know in order to do this

Comment: It sounds like you need loops

Comment: How would I use a loop to do this?

Comment: To fully solve this you'd need to write a simple parser. You might want to look into Reverse Polish Notation which is sometimes used for calculators as it is easier to parse than standard notation.

Comment: If you want to just support + and - or * and / you only need to use a loop since you only need to calculate from the left. However, if you want to use any combination of the four you'll need to parse your expressions. I suggest learning how to use Lex/Yacc or (Flex/Bison) for more complicated expressions. https://www.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/aixprggd/genprogc/ie_prog_4lex_yacc.htm has sample code for a simple Lex/Yacc calculator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a while loop to read from standard input. (std::cin) Some basic code to read from a while loop, and add the input to a sum is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
    std::string line = "";
    double sum = 0.0;
    while(line != "end"){
        std::cout<<"The current sum is: "<<sum<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Enter the number you would like to add or \"end\" to exit: ";
        std::cin>>line;
        sum += atof(line.c_str());
    }
    std::cout<<"The final sum is: "<<sum<<std::endl;
}
```

This will read numbers until it receives the input "end".

Comment: Best code response so far. One caveat: `atof` silently exits when it encounters a bad string. ['strtod'](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) allows the program to catch most errors by testing the `end` parameter for the string-ending NULL.

Comment: @user4581301 Quite true, however as the OP stated they are a beginner and I didn't want to confuse them with extra error checking code. It is generally easier for starters to understand "providing the right input" rather than "validating the right input".

Comment: Agreed. One step at a time. Get data in. Test it. Get *right* data in. Test it. Operate on data. Test it. I just like to leave some crumbs for later.

Comment: @user4581301 Very well said and I absolutely agree. Thank you for the critique.

Answer (score 2):

For parsing and evaluating expressions that include infix operators, few things are simpler than the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Implementing this in C++ is scarcely different than any other language with a container library (or built-in support) that provides [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29)s and [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29)s. Here, you'll want to use `std::stack` and `std::queue`. The input to your program could be a single line (containing an expression typed by the user) read from `std::cin` (standard input, or the console) into an `std::string`.

This will not only permit expressions of any reasonable length, but also correctly handle arbitrary nesting of parenthesized sub-expressions, evaluation of special functions, and custom operators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. You can use `vector` of `int`s. Get user's input and calculate sum of elements from `vector`. Put this in loop and that is what you wanted.

Comment: Works, but doubles the workload. One loop to load the vector and then another loop to process the vector. If you need to store the input, taking order of operations into account for example, @defube 's suggestion of stacks and queues is the better.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << "argument " << i << " is " << argv[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sidesteps part of the OP's request * without being asked how many numbers he wants*